# Delete rows based on semi-unique ID string

Tags: excel, vba

I have a series of semi-unique IDs, similar to the below:

```
XX123456/01
XX123456/02
XX123456/03
XX122222/01
XX122222/02
XX122222/03
XX155555/01
XX155555/05
```

The lengths are always the same, and always split by a delimiter with a secondary unique ID following.

I want to run down a column and delete rows, leaving only the row with the largest secondary unique ID, e.g.:

```
XX123456/03
XX122222/03
XX155555/05
```

What sort of logic do I need to apply for this?

I know how to deal with standard duplicates by looping down the column and adding each ID into an array, and deleting a row if the ID is already in the array, but I am not sure how to deal with the secondary unique ID.

Comment: That could work, although I don't know for certain that they would be in numerical order. I suppose I could order them first then loop from the bottom up?

Answer (score 0):

If this is a one-time job it would be safer and easier to do it without VBA. If you must do it using VBA, you could do the below:

```
Sub RowDelete()
  Dim Rng     As Range

  Set Rng = Range("C2") 'Change this to the column and cell where your data begins (below the header).
  Rng.Sort key1:=Rng, order1:=xlAscending 'Sorts your data in ascending order.

  'The For Loop below is a little ugly, but it tests the number to the left of the delimiter and finds
  'the largest value to the right of the delimiter. It fills a temp column 50 columns over with the value "DELETE".
  For i = 1 To Range("C2", Rng.End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
    If Left(Rng.Offset(i, 0).Value, 8) = Left(Rng.Offset(i - 1, 0).Value, 8) _
    And Right(Rng.Offset(i, 0).Value, 2) > Right(Rng.Offset(i - 1, 0).Value, 2) Then Rng.Offset(i - 1, 50).Value = "DELETE"
  Next i

  'Loops through the temp column and deletes the row if its value is "DELETE"
  For i = Range("C2", Rng.End(xlDown)).Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
    If Rng.Offset(i - 1, 50).Value = "DELETE" Then Rng.Offset(i - 1, 50).EntireRow.Delete
  Next i
End Sub
```

Please keep in mind that I don't know the size or importance of your project. I quickly threw this together in hopes that it might give you insight on ways to solve this problem.